# How painful is it to use multiple Apple IDs with the MAS?

Tags: mac-appstore, apple-id

I have two different Apple IDs, associated with Apple Stores in different countries. On my iPhone, some apps were purchased with one ID, some with the other. This used to be really painful in iOS 5, but it's not so bad in iOS 6: the system detects all apps that need updates, no matter what account I am currently using for the App Store, and it asks for login information for the other account when it needs to update an app purchased with it.

On my Mac, all apps were purchased with a single account (including Mountain Lion). However, the other account is associated with the US store, which tends to have better prices, so I'd like to buy some apps there. But how bad is the experience going to be? Is the Mac App Store going to detect updates for apps in both accounts, and install the updates with minimal fuss? Or am I going to miss out on half the updates, potentially including OS updates?

I would like to understand the exact experience I'm facing before I go this way, because I don't want to have the same mess I had with iOS 5 on my Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really, I personally used multiple account. You see update notifications for both accounts; however, to perform the updates for apps purchased with another account you have to manually log out and log into the other account.

Comment: So if I have the OS and a few apps under account A, and other apps under account B, and I am normally logged into account B, I still get all update notifications for both A and B? And when it's time to update it asks me for A's login credentials? Or do I have to update the apps on B, then sign out of the store with B, then sign in with A, then update the apps with A, then sign out with A, then sign back in with B?

Comment: @LaC Unfortunately that is true, you will have to sign out from B and then sign in with A. You will see update for both though.

Comment: @LaC Another thing is International Stores, if something is only available in another store, you won't be able to see its update. You will have to switch to that store manually.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies things. I think I'm going to try to stick to one store for as long as possible, even if it costs me a few extra dollars...